# Localization for scripts

Tags: c#, .net, localization, ironpython

I have a new piece of software I'm working on for my company that potentially will need some localization options for our plant in Mexico. As far as the application goes, C#/.NET has some great localization features that I will utilize. The new program will be making use of scripts that will have messages pop-up to the user, and those are probably the most important ones for localization. They'll be written in [Iron]Python and we are currently, for other scripts/software, maintaining two separate scripts for localization (and some other small changes that could be implemented via logic). What's the best way to localize a script so we can have just one script?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to remove all of the user-facing strings from your script, and instead look up what string is to be shown based on the current language. For example, instead of:

```
print 'Hello, World'
```

use

```
print _('Hello, World')

def _(key):
    if currentlang == 'es':
        return localized_text_es[key]
    else:
        return key

localized_text_es = { 'Hello, World': '¡Hola, mundo' }
```

You could fill `localized_text` at startup from `en.txt`/`es.txt` files, or you could hardcode both languages into the scripts, or whatever other method you choose.